# Advmame on pi with raspbmc

Tags: audio, emulation

I've been trying to get advanceMAME to run on my Pi but I haven't had any luck.I installed advmame via [this](http://sheasilverman.com/rpi/raspbian/debs/advancemame_1.2-1_armhf.deb) package, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Assertion 'l' failed at pulsecore/flist.c function pa_flist_pop(). Aborting.
Signal SIGABRT[fffffffah],from code at (nill)
```

Anyone has any idea of what does it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable Sound on Pi. Raspbmc by default doesn't use ALSA (advanced linux sound architecture):

sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835

sudo echo 'snd_bcm2835' >> /etc/modules

1. Download and install advmame binary from here:
   http://blog.sheasilverman.com/2012/11/better-advancemame-debs-with-sound/
   Don't forget to install libsdl1.2-dev.

Start emulator: advmame romname
e.g advmame frogger
Use romname without path and without .zip-extension!

Happy gaming!